# Why are these two mysql queries different?

Tags: mysql

```
select distinct p.product_id from cscart_products p 
    left join product_bikes pb on p.product_id = pb.product_id
    left join cscart_product_options po on po.product_id = p.product_id
    left join cscart_product_option_variants pov on pov.option_id = po.option_id
    left join variant_bikes vb on vb.variant_id = pov.variant_id
    where pb.bike_id = 111 or vb.bike_id = 111
```

And:

```
select distinct p.product_id from cscart_products p 
    left join product_bikes pb on p.product_id = pb.product_id and pb.bike_id = 111
    left join cscart_product_options po on po.product_id = p.product_id
    left join cscart_product_option_variants pov on pov.option_id = po.option_id
    left join variant_bikes vb on vb.variant_id = pov.variant_id and vb.bike_id = 111
```

Return different result sets, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first query has an OR in the WHERE clause:

```
WHERE pb.bike_id = 111 OR vb.bike_id = 111
```

The second query effectively has AND instead, via the conditions:

```
LEFT JOIN product_bikes pb ON p.product_id = pb.product_id AND pb.bike_id = 111
...
LEFT JOIN variant_bikes vb ON vb.variant_id = pov.variant_id AND vb.bike_id = 111
```

---

> Bonus question: is there a way with joins to make it behave the same and benefit from having smaller joins for performance?

There is a way to write the query, but it isn't necessarily any faster because the method (that I'm thinking of) uses UNION:

```
select distinct p.product_id from cscart_products p 
    left join product_bikes pb on p.product_id = pb.product_id and pb.bike_id = 111
    left join cscart_product_options po on po.product_id = p.product_id
    left join cscart_product_option_variants pov on pov.option_id = po.option_id
    left join variant_bikes vb on vb.variant_id = pov.variant_id -- and vb.bike_id = 111
UNION
select distinct p.product_id from cscart_products p 
    left join product_bikes pb on p.product_id = pb.product_id -- and pb.bike_id = 111
    left join cscart_product_options po on po.product_id = p.product_id
    left join cscart_product_option_variants pov on pov.option_id = po.option_id
    left join variant_bikes vb on vb.variant_id = pov.variant_id and vb.bike_id = 111
```

There probably is a better way of doing it, such that you have a UNION sub-query, along the lines of:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.product_id
  FROM      cscart_products                AS p 
  LEFT JOIN cscart_product_options         AS po  ON po.product_id = p.product_id
  LEFT JOIN cscart_product_option_variants AS pov ON pov.option_id = po.option_id
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT vb.product_id FROM variant_bikes AS vb WHERE vb.bike_id = 111
             UNION
             SELECT pb.product_id FROM product_bikes AS pb WHERE pb.bike_id = 111
            ) AS pv ON pv.product_id = p.product_id
```

Since you aren't (in the example) selecting data from the `cscart_product_options` or `cscart_product_options_variants` tables, you could eliminate those from the query.  You should also look at whether the LEFT JOIN with the sub-query is appropriate; I think it more likely that you want an inner join.  There may well be more work that can be done to improve the performance.

Comment: ok great :)  Thank you it won't let me award you the answer for 11 more minutes.  Bonus question: is there a way with joins to make it behave the same and benefit from having smaller joins for performance?

Comment: Add `WHERE pb.bike_id IS NOT NULL OR vb.bike_id IS NOT NULL` to the end of the second query.

Comment: Would other join types maybe work as well such as using a full join for those joins Barmar?

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, if I don't join the other tables though I have no way to know which variants belong to the product but I'll keep chipping at it thanks :)  I tried inner join too but those make no data sets return at all :(

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Jonathan said.  In the first query, the WHERE forces it that you don't get ANY results UNLESS (pb.bike_id = 111 or vb.bike_id = 111) is true.  In the second query, you will get all DISTINCT [product_id]s even though only one row will be able to join via the LEFT JOINs.

If you are getting a lot of results from the second query vs. the first, that's way.  The easier way to see this is by putting more in your SELECT so:

```
SELECT p.product_id, pb.bike_id ...
```

You'll notice if you do that, that the first query will have 111 in every product it displays, but the second query will have a lot of NULL values for pb.bike_id.

Make sense?